# How to solve Nested quantifiers in regex?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

Getting stuck at

```
my $count=grep {/$str_check/} @arr_name ;
```

when

```
$str_check = 'C/C++'
```

It throws `Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/'C/C++ <-- HERE '/ at acr_def_abb_use.pl line 288`

I tried by changing into

```
my $count=grep {/"$str_check"/} @arr_name ;
```

and

```
my $count=grep {/'$str_check'/} @arr_name ;
```

But both didn't work.  Any one please help me out with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to generate a regular expression pattern that matches the text. Specifically, you want `C/C\+\+`.

```
my $text  = 'C/C++';
my $pat   = quotemeta($text);
my $count = grep { /$pat/ } @arr_name;
```

or

```
my $text  = 'C/C++';
my $count = grep { /\Q$text\E/ } @arr_name;
```

(The `\E` can be omitted since it's at the end.)

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce your problem, but it is good practice to use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for special characters:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr_name = ('dgsdjhg','bar C/C++ foo', 'bbbb', 'C/C++');
my $str_check = quotemeta 'C/C++';
my $count = grep { /$str_check/ } @arr_name;
print "$count\n";
```